# Controlling problem in android layouts

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, layoutparams

I tried to show new view on the center of relativelayout.
But the new view always places on the top of screen.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService("layout_inflater");
dest = inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchlayout, ViewGroup)      
this.findViewById(R.layout.pdfview));
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
dest.setLayoutParams(params);
this.addContentView(dest, params);
```

Comment: parent layout xml would be make the problem understand better.

Comment: Ofcourse it will realtive layout work in this manner the item added last will be on top

Comment: It will be added to the top , if the new view you are adding has the maximum height in the relative layout.

Comment: I have seen this before and changing to using the view's oriinal layout parameters seems to help. i.e.:

`LayoutParams lp = dest.getLayoutParams();
dest.addRule(theRuleToAdd);`